# Algorithms or references on how to detect and potentially remove jumps in stock returns

Tags: statistics, statistical-finance

Sorry if this has been asked before. Thought this is a standard question but searching on web didn't give me too much useful links.

Assuming a series of stock prices, how to detect and potentially remove big jumps in this series? We want to keep round humps but detect/remove sudden jumps.

For one example, assuming the series is [10, 11, 10, 12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 19, 18, 50, 20, 19]. Notice that the sub-range of [12, 15, 17, 19, 22, 19] isn't a jump since it's ramping up and down gradually. In this case, we don't want to label it as jump and want to keep it. But the value "50" is apparently a jump.

I can think of several heuristic ways to do this. But wondering if there is some more statistically stable algorithms or references. Any inputs or pointers are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: [This method](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/74229/54838) might help.